# Build error when using image picker in flutter

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

I'm trying to implement an image-picker in my app but every time I get image picker packages, there is a build failure. And I'm not able to understand it. Please heal me to fix this problem. I'm using image_picker: ^0.6.6+4.

---

```
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 780

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 58s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        59.5s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```